# Including Bootstrap's Navbar on every page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a website for myself, with several HTML files, and wanted to use the navbar that Bootstrap offers. I got it to work where I would simply type the same code in each HTML file, but I don't want to do that since it's hard to make changes to the navbar and just bad practice.

My question is how do I include the navbar on every one of my website's pages (every one of the HTML files) without having to copy and paste the navbar's code in every file? Below is a copy of my navbar's code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 </head>
  <body>

  <header class = "navbar-default">
     <div class="container">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role = "navi">
       
         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="mainPage.html">Connor Svrcek</a>
         </div>
         <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="resume.html">Resume <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="projects.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">SpartaHack 2017</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                 <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                 <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="connect.html">Connect</a></li>
           </ul>
           
           
         </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
       </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
     </nav>
   </header>

   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
  </body>
 </html>
```

I know this was long, but thank you all for the help!

Comment: if you want to use jquery, add a file like `nav-partial.html` to the root of your site, add a `<nav id="nav">` to your pages, and use something like `$('#nav').load('/nav-partial.html');`

Comment: You have to use jquery/javascript for this or if you are using some server side code like php etc. then that can do the trick for you! In html iself this is not possible.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any longer, since it violates CORS restrictions. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp

Answer (score 0):

**You cant remove the code, you have to have something there that you copy and paste.**
You can use an `<iframe>` element. Simply take the navbar code, and make an `<iframe>` and copy that into every page. make sure you have the correct html document and the iframe is pointing to the path of that document.

You can also use jQuery like Michael Coker said:

> add a file like nav-partial.html to the root of your site, add a `<nav id="nav">`to your pages, and use something like $('#nav').load('/nav-partial.html');

```
$('#nav').load('/nav-partial.html');
```

Comment: All you're doing is making him copy that into every file instead of what he's trying not to copy into every file.

Comment: But its one small line the iframe is.

Comment: It doesn't matter. He doesn't want to have to copy anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this without Jquery or iframes

First create an shtml file containing the navbar code only e.g. nav.shtml

then call that file from your php file:

```
<?php include_once("nav.shtml"); ?>
```

You will need to add a handler in cpanel (or whatever your hosting provides)

Handler: server-parsed, 
extension: .html